# How to input external variable as in laravel mailer in users controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function in user controller in laravel that allows users to enter their name and email in a form and send an email to administrator. But when I try to the variable containing them in the MailTo function, it gives error. Here is my code:

```
public function send_email_contact_us(){
        $name = Input::get('name');
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $message_contact = Input::get('message');
        $sender_email = Input::get('email');
            $sender_name = Input::get('name');

        $validator = Validator::make(
            array(

                'name' => $name,
                'email' => $email

            ), array(
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required',

            )
        );

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $error_messages = $validator->messages()->all();
            return Redirect::back()->with('flash_errors',"Message not sent, please try again.");
        }
        else
        {
            $data=array("name"=>$name,"email"=>$email,"message_contact"=>$message_contact);
            Mail::send('emails.contactus',$data, function($message)
            {
       $message->from($sender_email, $sender_name); // THIS GIVES ERROR
        $message->to("admin@admin.com")->subject('Contact Us');
            });
            return Redirect::back()->with('flash_success',"Message sent successfully.");
        }
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `it gives error` You leave it for us? To guess the error?

Comment: So which problem are you facing? What is your question? What does not work? What would you expect and what actually happens? Which errors do you see? Kindly provide us details.

Comment: @u_mulder I tried to find a way around it but couldnt do so, thats why I posted it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to this

```
Mail::send('emails.contactus',$data, function($message) use($sender_email,$sender_name)
{
   $message->from($sender_email, $sender_name);
   $message->to("admin@admin.com")->subject('Contact Us');
});
```

To use external variables in a closure you have to import the variable into the closure by using the **use** keyword